# getNumColumns() doesn't update?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Basically what I'm trying to do is insert a certain number of values into a spreadsheet via a script. The way I have it set up, it inserts each value separately, calling the function x amount of times.

Let's say I have 4 values. I want to insert all the values into row 1 then, column 1, column 2, column 3, column 4. What's happening right now in my code, is it inserts all of the values into column 1 only, and it just overwrites anything already in column 1, so I only end up with the last value.

```
var column = sheet.getDataRange().getNumColumns() + 1;

sheet.getRange(1, column).setValue(question);
```

If I add in that + 1 to getNumColumns, it will add all four values, but into columns 2, 3, 4, and 5. So basically, if I don't use the + 1, the getNumColumns() never updates, and each time a value is inserted it stays at 1. I have no idea why this is and have been searching for quite some time now for an answer.

EDITED CODE:

```
var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var data = range.getValues();


  if (range.isBlank()){
    var column = 1;
    sheet.getRange(1, column).setValue(question);
  }else{
    var column = sheet.getDataRange().getNumColumns();
    sheet.getRange(1, column).setValue(question);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your data range initializes as column 1, meaning that the first time through you add 1+1 to get column 2, etc. The simplest approach is probably to write an if-statement so that when `getDataRange().getNumColumns() == 1`, you don't add the 1, but you add it every other time. Even better would be finding a way to initialize the data range to 0 instead of 1, if the API allows that.

Edited: On second thoughts, the safer way would be to check to see if the data range is blank, rather than if the number of columns is 1. You can use the `isBlank()` method for that.

Comment: I tried editing it as you described, and it still is wanting to insert all of the values into the first column each time, overwriting whatever was there before it.

Comment: You need the `+ 1` back in your `else` statement.